# Rails 4: Undefined method on module

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, dsl

I have a module in `app/misc/dsl/builder.rb` that has this code

```
module Dsl
  class Builder
    def initialize(context, &block)
      return if not block_given?

      parent_context = block.binding.eval "self"
      parent_context.extend Proxy
      parent_context.object = context 

      parent_context.instance_eval &block
    end
  end

  def self.set_context(context, &block)
    Dsl::Builder.new(context, &block)
  end
end
```

Note: this directory `misc` is preloaded in `application.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '{**/}'), 
  Rails.root.join('app', 'misc', '{**/}')
]
```

Then, somewhere in the text (lets say at `foo.rb`) I have this code:

```
Dsl.set_context(obj) do
  #some code with obj receiving messages
end
```

The test stack we are using consists on Zeus+Guard+Rspec. Now, lets say I rewrite the code to something not working

```
Dsl.set_context(obj) do
  asdqwe #this message does not exists
end
```

From times to times, I receive this baffling message

```
  1) SomeOtherClass search_hash receiving keywords params should query for those keywords
     Failure/Error: subject.search_hash
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `set_context' for Dsl:Module
     # ./app/misc/product_query.rb:116:in `base_search_hash'
     # ./app/misc/product_query.rb:25:in `search_hash'
     # ./spec/misc/product_query_spec.rb:78:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # -e:1:in `<main>'
```

instead of the correct message that should be regarding `undefined method asdqwe`

Any clue about this?

Comment: did you restart the server? hoe are you preloading in the application.rb ? seem like it isn't load. could you try `requrie 'app/misc/dsl/builder.rb'` ?

Comment: @lalo just updated the question. I tried `require_relative 'app/misc/dsl/builder.rb'` and then yes, it loads. It seems a loading problem but can't figure out what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look  [here](http://www.williambharding.com/blog/technology/rails-3-autoload-modules-and-classes-in-production/)

it says:

> Rails 3 has been updated such that classes/modules (henceforth, C/M)
>   are lazy loaded from the autoload paths as they are needed

so, you can do `require_relative 'app/misc/dsl/builder.rb'` in your rspec_helper.rb (can it be better with just `require`?) The problem must be that the loader doesn't know in advance where to find `Dsl.set_context`, but he will know once you have referenced `Dsl::Builder`

Hope it helps